# Finding out what the staking rewards are

Tags: staking, adaptive-issuance

I understood I could only find staking rewards when unstaking, but I see this without unstaking. Why has the staking balance increased for these stakers? (I made no additional transactions.)

Cycle 20:  The staked balance of tz1XDL5EuVrKXxa6bawcA7oRfLBgvH2uWtWi is "31000000000".

Cycle 21: The staked balance of tz1XDL5EuVrKXxa6bawcA7oRfLBgvH2uWtWi is "31154286533".

Comment: Please add context this is on oxfordnet and in the context of the proposed staking system :pray:

Answer (score 1):

Under the [new staking system in the Oxford upgrade proposals](https://research-development.nomadic-labs.com/adaptive-issuance.html#staked-funds-management), bakers (and eventually others stakers) have indeed to manually manipulate their frozen stakes -- what has being called insofar "frozen deposits".

However, that doesn't mean their `staked balance` doesn't change -- as e.g. rewards paid to their frozen stake increase their balance.

The pseudo-operations to `unstake` and `finalize` funds allow bakers/stakers to reduce a portion of the stake, making such funds part of their *liquid*, `spendable balance`.

(This answer builds upon [@nicolasochem](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/users/580/nicolasochem)'s reply on [Tezos Baking Slack](https://tezos-baking.slack.com/archives/CGJSJTREC/p1694029576844249))